# Маршрутизация CodeIgniter URI Routing

Tags: codeigniter, маршрутизация, uri

Вопрос следующий.
Если юзер залогинен, при входе на сайт (http://localhost:3000/sitename/) он должен автоматически попадать на страницу dashboard.

Если юзер не залогинен, при входе на сайт (http://localhost:3000/sitename/) он должен автоматически попадать на страницу login.

Если страницы не существует, то он должен попадать на страницу 404.

Comment: В чем вопрос заключается?

Comment: Как это лучше сделать в codeignater через сессию или просто тупо через проверки(if) и пути к контролерам менять???

Comment: Проверяйте на наличие сессии, скажем, `$_SESSION['logged_in']`, страницу регистрации\логина. Если сессия присутствует, редирект на dashboard: `header("Location: /dashboard");`

Comment: Спасибо попробуем!